# Laptop loses packets with connected monitor

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

An issue appears only in a room which is two walls from a router and only with HP monitor. When the monitor is connected to the laptop via HDMI it starts to lose packages through WiFi. Different combinations of restart laptop with connected/disconnected monitor and charge give same result.

Other monitor MSI with laptop work well in this room. Monitor HP with laptop work well in other rooms. Smartphones and Windows laptop works fine.

Devices:

Dell Vostro 3500 (P83F) (Ubuntu 20.04)
HP E243 Monitor

```
lspci |grep -E "VGA|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile) 
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
```

After research in internet, I found a command `dmesg -w` and after monitor connection to laptop I have this:

```
[59859.700549] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 11 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [149, 188] HW [149, 188] FH TRB=0x0c010b0a4
[59859.700778] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[59859.701155] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[59859.701161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[59859.701166] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 46.6bf1df06.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
[59859.701172] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[59859.701176] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000026F0 | trm_hw_status0
[59859.701179] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[59859.701183] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004882DA | branchlink2
```

beside this I have other red logs:

```
[   91.072026] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   91.072114] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: can't change power state from D3hot to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   91.072166] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Controller not ready at resume -19
[   91.072169] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
[   91.072173] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: HC died; cleaning up

[   96.191381] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[   97.929581] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
```

I've tried to update drivers with command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, but it didn't change situation.

My zero knowledge in electricity things say me, that also could be problem with voltage in power socket. This idea I would like to check soon.

Maybe somebody understand what cause such a behavior.

EDIT:

After few Ubuntu updates error `iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Queue 11 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [149, 188] HW [149, 188] FH TRB=0x0c010b0a4` disappered.

But PCI errors are depend on changing input port.

Comment: You can try changing the channels on the wifi router, try 1 or the highest channel (11 in US).  It might be enough of a shift to get around the interference.

Comment: no, this didn't help